# android how to save date in sqlite

Tags: android, date

I am retrieving date from datepicker and passing its value in main activity and setting this date in a textView. Well textview shows the correct date which has been picked from datepicker but when I saves this date by pulling from date textview, database entry always shows the current(today's) date. Please find my code below

`//Database code
public long insertcontact(String date)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd"); 
        Date ddate = new Date();
initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, dateFormat.format(ddate));
return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}`

Comment: You insert a `new Date()` which always refers to the current time and date.

Answer (score 0):

### Mistake:

You are trying to put `new Date()` value which returns the current date and time.

```
Date ddate = new Date();
initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, dateFormat.format(ddate));
```

### Solution:

I assume you are passing selected date in `insertcontact(String date)` as a parameter, which is actually a correct date.

```
Date ddate = new Date();
initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, dateFormat.format(date));
```